# Oracle UPDATE syntax with JOIN and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join, where-clause

I need to update one of my tables, and can't seem to get the syntax right.  I've tried a few different approaches, but not having any lunch.

I'm getting a "SQL command not properly ended" error with this one...

```
UPDATE TESTDTA.F4941
SET TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN=TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1=TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM
FROM TESTDTA.F4941
INNER JOIN TESTDTA.F4981
ON TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN    = TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
WHERE TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN = 647143
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ   > 110365
AND TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1   = 'DIS';
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously you need to move the set to after the select ... as follows. However what I think is missing form previous advice is that you need to alias each column in the select. e.g.

```
UPDATE (SELECT TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN as A_RDSTN,TESTDTA.F4981.RSDSTN AS B_RSDSTN
FROM TESTDTA.F4941
INNER JOIN TESTDTA.F4981
ON TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN    = TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
WHERE TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN = 647143
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ   > 110365
AND TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1   = 'DIS')
SET A_RSDSTN = B_RSDSTN
```

For brevity I have only given an example of one column update. You would need to alias each column separately that needs to be updated.

**You should also note that you need to have a primary key or unique index on the table you are updating. Otherwise you will get a *"ORA-01779 Cannot modify a column that maps to a non key-preserved table."***

Comment: the table does have a primary key, but it consists of two columns, rather than a single column PK.  could that be the problem?

Comment: you need to be sure also that for each row in the table you are updating there is **AT MOST** one row in the joined to table. If this is a problem you may have to abandon this approach of an updatable select and go perhaps with Guarav's suggestion of using a merge statement.

Comment: Please also see [this excellent post](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/i-wish-5/) from the much respected Jonathan Lewis on updatable join views. Look at the comments by users also on some interesting approaches to getting around key preserved errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE (SELECT *
FROM TESTDTA.F4941
INNER JOIN TESTDTA.F4981
ON TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN    = TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
WHERE TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN = 647143
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ   > 110365
AND TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1   = 'DIS')
SET TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN=TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1=TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM
```

Move the SET clause after the join.

Comment: i get this error with your method.  Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TESTDTA"."F4941": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: i had actually tried that also, but still no good.   Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TESTDTA"."F4981"."FHUOM": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Why don't you try debugging it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `merge` statement,when i have to join

```
MERGE INTO TESTDTA.F4941
USING TESTDTA.F4981
ON (TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN    = TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN = 647143
--AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
 AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ   > 110365
 AND TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1   = 'DIS'
  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN=TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ
          ,TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1=TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM;
```

Comment: i get this error when I try your method.  Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00925: missing INTO keyword
00925. 00000 -  "missing INTO keyword"

Comment: @user1521068:I have added into keyword after Merge

Comment: It works if I comment out one of the WHERE clauses (AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0), but gives me this error if I leave it in...  SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "TESTDTA"."F4941"."RSDSTN"
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
*Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `SET` from your `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE TESTDTA.F4941
SET (TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN,TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1) = 
(SELECT TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM
...
```

my new code...

```
UPDATE TESTDTA.F4941
SET TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN=TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1=TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM = (SELECT TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN,
TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN,
TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1,
TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ,
TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1
FROM TESTDTA.F4941
INNER JOIN TESTDTA.F4981
ON TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN    = TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
WHERE TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN = 647143
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ   > 110365
AND TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1   = 'DIS';
```

Comment: You still have the `set<column> = <other column>` in your update statement.  Check out my post again. You need to have `set (col1, col2,col3...) = (select col1, col2, col3...)`.  Not `set col1 = othertable.col1...`.

Comment: when written this way, it just loops and never completes

Answer (score 0):

finally got this to work...

```
MERGE INTO TESTDTA.F4941 DST
USING (SELECT DISTINCT TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN,
    TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN,
    TESTDTA.F4941.RSUMD1,
    TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ,
    TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN,
    TESTDTA.F4981.FHRTDQ,
    TESTDTA.F4981.FHUOM,
    TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1
FROM TESTDTA.F4941
INNER JOIN TESTDTA.F4981
ON TESTDTA.F4941.RSSHPN    = TESTDTA.F4981.FHSHPN
WHERE TESTDTA.F4941.RSDSTN = 0
AND TESTDTA.F4941.RSADDJ   > 110365
AND TESTDTA.F4981.FHCGC1   = 'DIS') SRC
ON (DST.RSSHPN = SRC.FHSHPN)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE

SET DST.RSDSTN = round(SRC.FHRTDQ/10000,0), DST.RSUMD1 = SRC.FHUOM;
```